# Filling to Axis as Arrow

Tags: plotting, filling, compatibility

In version 9 I could do the following with the output as shown.

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}], PlotRange -> All, 
Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> (Arrow[#] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now in version  10.0.2 with the same input I get the following.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How do I get my arrows back? PlotTheme Classic does not help. Thanks

Comment: `plot /. Line -> Arrow` can be a quick fix.

Comment: Another quick fix is `PlotMarkers -> "\[FilledUpTriangle]"`

Comment: @ybeltukov Not exactly the same but very clever!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems this form still works:

```
ListPlot[
  Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}],
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, Arrow[#] &}}
]
```

[image]

---

### Caveat

The use of a `Function` as a filling style seemed undocumented, therefore one cannot expect the feature to remain or remain unchanged in new versions of *Mathematica*.  ybeltukov notes in a comment that the form above does not work with multiple plot sets.  In light of this I suppose that it would be better to write our own plotting function using `Graphics` primitives if this kind of customization is needed, since that functionality is documented and hopefully will not incompatibly change in future releases.  (This is often faster as well as it avoids a lot of overhead associated with generalized plotting.)  Post-processing is quick but also easily breaks between versions as the plotting output format often changes.

Comment: How to do the same thing for several lists of points? Even `{1 -> {Axis, Arrow[#] &}, 2 -> {Axis, Arrow[#] &}}` produces a strange error `Filling::invfillentry: "{2->{Axis,Arrow[#1]&},2->{Axis,Arrow[#1]&}} is not a valid Filling specification. "`

Comment: @ybeltukov Problem noted in the answer, along with my thoughts.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Many thanks for your answer which I have now accepted. Also your comment. Probably a Graphics construct is best as you suggest.